# How can I protect a workbook's structure using Apache POI, just like what I can do on the Excel GUI?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

Like this: Excel GUI->Review->Protect Workbook->Protect workbook for structure->input password.

I've tried the api **HSSFWorkbook.writeProtectWorkbook(String password, String username)**, didn't work as I expected. Inputting password on opening the file would be quite unnecessary on my case, but only structure protection is needed.

Comment: For `XSSFWorkbook` this would be [XSSFWorkbook.lockStructure](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#lockStructure()) in combination with [XSSFWorkbook.setWorkbookPassword](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#setWorkbookPassword(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.HashAlgorithm)). But for `HSSFWorkbook` I don't know since I do not bother myself with file formats which are decades old and outdated.

Comment: Thanks Axel, but in our project, only **HSSFWorkbook** and **SXSSFWorkbook** are used, and they happen not to share this interface method with **XSSFWorkbook**. Sorry but I should have mentioned this. It is quite strange that SXSSFWorkbook is not extended from XSSFWorkbook...

Comment: For `SXSSFWorkbook` you could do  `XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); wb.lockStructure(); wb.setWorkbookPassword("password", HashAlgorithm.sha512); SXSSFWorkbook sxssfwb = new SXSSFWorkbook(wb); ...`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Structure lock in HSSFWorkbook possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69120284/structure-lock-in-hssfworkbook-possible)

Answer (score 0):

For those who use `SXSSFWorkbook` instead of other workbook,
you can protect your workbook as the same as Excel GUI does:

```
// assuming the class of this workbook is SXSSFWorkbook 
SXSSFWorkbook wb = (SXSSFWorkbook) workbook; 

// prevent from modifying the content 
wb.getSheet("sheetName");
sheet.protectSheet("modify-passwd"); 
wb.setSheetVisibility(wb.getSheetIndex(sheet), SheetVisibility.HIDDEN); 

// keep hiding until entering the password 
XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = wb.getXSSFWorkbook();
xssfWorkbook.lockStructure();
xssfWorkbook.setWorkbookPassword("hide-passwd", HashAlgorithm.sha512); 

// Wow ,it works!
```

> According to Axel Richter's answer. Thanks a lot