# Structure lock in HSSFWorkbook possible?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, hssfworkbook

In the POI **XSSFWorkbook**, the methods **lockStructure** and **lockWindows** exist with which an Excel Workbook can be protected. (Function in excel menue under "Review->Protect Workbook...")

The function of these methods is analogous to the Workbook.protect method in Excel:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.protect

Is there any way to enable this protection in a **HSSFWorkbook**?

I have already tried the **writeProtectWorkbook** method from **HSSFWorkbook**, but it does not do the same as the methods in the **XSSFWorkbook**. The method **writeProtectWorkbook** sets an open password.
Probably I have to modify the "worksheet protection block" which is described in section 5.82 here on page 200: http://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf

Does anyone know how I can get this block with POI?

I use poi:5.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out myself how to enable Workbook Protection.
In the **InternalWorkbook** there is a list of records. These contain the record types **ProtectRecord**, **WindowProtectRecord** and **PasswordRecord**.
With these you can set the Workbook Protection:

```java
List<Record> records = ((HSSFWorkbook) wb).getInternalWorkbook().getRecords();
for (Record record : records) {
    if (record instanceof ProtectRecord) {
        ((ProtectRecord) record).setProtect(true);
    } else if (record instanceof WindowProtectRecord) {
        ((WindowProtectRecord) record).setProtect(true);
    } else if (record instanceof PasswordRecord) {
        ((PasswordRecord) record).setPassword((short) CryptoFunctions.createXorVerifier1("password"));
    }
}
```